aria-label locator containing backslash not found by Cypress
I am trying to get one of the checkboxes using the aria-label attributes but Cypress is not able to find it. It has a backslash in the value and I replaced it with two backslashes but still Cypress can't locate it.
It locates up to "class=checkbox-container checkbox-list-item" locator, but when going to the specific [aria-label="Default\PizzaID-RedOnionsID"] checkbox, Cypress says locator not found.
Trying to get it by cy.get('[aria-label="Default\PizzaID-RedOnionsID"]') produces no result. I also tried cy.get('.checkbox-container.checkbox-list-item').find('[aria-label="Default\PizzaID-RedOnionsID"]')
I can see the element in the DOM inspector:


The problem is \ is a special character used to "escape" the next character in the string.
For example if you want to use a double-quote inside a string like this
const myString = "a string containing a double " quote"

you need to add an escape character like this
const myString = "a string containing a double \" quote"

But how to escape the escape character if you want it in the string?
Generally you add another escape character, but in your example that doesn't work either. You need to add three escape characters to the query selector
cy.get('[aria-label="Default\\\\PizzaID-RedOnionsID"]') 



A more conventional way is to select on part of the string and ignore the escape character.
If you add $= to the selector, it only compares the end of the aria-label.
cy.get('[aria-label$="PizzaID-RedOnionsID"]')  


or you can slice the backslash out
cy.get('[aria-label^="Default"][aria-label$="PizzaID-RedOnionsID"]')


